# Is there any way to get a cursor position in an editor in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to get the current position of the cursor in an editor in xamarin froms. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the cursor position? If you mean how many alphabets are present in the text that you can get through the TextChangedEventArgs of an editor!

Comment: I mean the position of the cursor in a sentence. like index.

Comment: Xamarin does not provide the api , check https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5093 . You could try to use custom renderer.